# How to find out the ip address of the nodePort

Tags: kubernetes

I have exposed my deployment to specific NodePort. If I want to connect to this deployment in cluster, how can I find the ip address of such NodePort?

Answer (score 11):

You access NodePort service with `<node-ip>:<node-port>`.

#### 1. Check Node IP

To check `node-ip`, you can execute the following command:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                                                STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION           INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     OS-IMAGE                             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
gke-rafal-test-cluster-default-pool-ef8193e3-1450   Ready    <none>   6m47s   v1.13.11-gke.23   192.168.1.234   35.188.23.46    Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.138+        docker://18.9.7
gke-rafal-test-cluster-default-pool-ef8193e3-1bd4   Ready    <none>   6m47s   v1.13.11-gke.23   192.168.1.230   34.67.114.201   Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.138+        docker://18.9.7
gke-rafal-test-cluster-default-pool-ef8193e3-q3c4   Ready    <none>   6m47s   v1.13.11-gke.23   192.168.1.228   34.69.230.23    Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.138+        docker://18.9.7
```

Any of node `EXTERNAL-IP` will work, so you can use `35.188.23.46`, `4.67.114.201`, or `34.69.230.23`. It doesn't matter.

If you don't see any `EXTERNAL-IP`, it may mean that your Kubernetes nodes do not have external IPs, so you just can't access them from outside.

If you run minikube, you can check node ip with the `minikube ip` command. If you run Docker Desktop Kubernetes, then node ip is `localhost`.

#### 2. Check Node Port

To check `node-port`, you can execute the following command.

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                        AGE
my-release-hazelcast             NodePort       10.208.7.24    <none>        5701:31096/TCP                 4s
```

The `<node-port>` is `31096`.

Comment: Another point to add here is : Make sure the service you have, has `externalTrafficPolicy : Cluster`. So that any the Nodeport proxies of any node can connect to the appropriate pod.

As explained in [link](https://www.asykim.com/blog/deep-dive-into-kubernetes-external-traffic-policies)

Example:
`
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vncdeployer1
spec:
  externalName: service_name_here
  externalTrafficPolicy : Cluster
....
....

`

Comment: @ChandrajyotiDas The external link is broken please update